# Microsoft Access Where Condition doesn't works in a subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, macros

I built a form called: "clientlist":
[image]

I put a macro with where condition on click:

> ="IDclient_logindata=" & [Maschere]![clientlist]![IDclient]

this means that when I click on an id client, access will open another form with the respective IDclient. For example if I click on IDclient 3:
[image]

it open another form called "client_logindata" filter to IDclient_logindata 3.
Then, I built a navigational form:
[image]
using clientlist as subform. But when I click a record, any record, it open every time the client_logindata form with IDclient_logindata form = 1, why it doesn' works in a subform?
Design View of "Navigation Form":[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved in this way: ="IDclient_logindata=" & [IDclient]

Comment: I was sceptical about this, but it does work. Indeed, that's the code that Access itself builds in this situation if you use it's wizards for the whole thing!

Answer (score 0):

When using a subform, [references to controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) need to be relative to the main form where the subform is treated as a child control.

Consider adjusting the conditional to the following structure. Do note this is the English version:

```
="IDclient_logindata=" & Forms!myMainForm!mySubform.Form!mySubformControl
```

Or specifically tailored to yours (be sure to get exact spelling of all objects):

```
="IDclient_logindata=" & Forms!NavigationForm!clientlist.Form!IDclient
```

Comment: One of the common reasons for such an error is incorrectly referring to an object. As mentioned, use exact names of objects (see control names in design view). If spaces are included in names, enclose in square brackets `[...]`. Also, don't use `Form\s` qualifier unless you are using Access in English version.

Comment: I put this: ="IDclient_logindata=" & [Maschere]![Navigation Form]![clientlist].[Maschera]![IDclient]

but doesn't work..error

Comment: Also, if you used the Navigation Form from the feature on ribbon, these forms are special and may actually have an inner layer of subforms. Can you screenshot the *design view* of this navigation form?

Comment: Potentially silly question: have you yet saved the Navigation Form and given it a name? Is it definitely called `[Navigation Form]`?

Comment: Is Navigation form placed inside another form (screenshot cuts this off)? If not, the above reference should work. Check actual names of subform and its control under *Property Sheet*. Sometimes the data source name or labels does not match actual control name.

Comment: I called Navigation Form as "Navigation Form".. Everything is ok but it doesn't work

Comment: but it's strange, because using another different database, it works without changed nothing for subforms

Comment: In case Parfait's last comment isn't clear, in this context the `clientlist` form may have a different name (check the subform control of the Nav form). It could be something like `subform1` (which I'd change to something meaningful). It is any such alternative name you need here.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has found a working solution which is much simpler than what follows. However, I was still interested to see if we could get something on the original model to work, and I'd guess that for users attempting to achieve the same thing using VBA rather than embedded macro's the following may still be useful.

---

The issue with the code in the original question is that the relevant form isn't open at the 'top level' but as a subform.

Form "normal" subforms, you'd refer to the control on the subform like this:

```
Forms!navform!clientlist.form!IDclient
```

Where `navform` is the name of the outer form. Or in the generalised case, like this:

```
Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName
```

However, the "Navigation Form" Wizard, when dragging subforms onto the *Add New* tab in *Layout* view doesn't name the subforms nicely. So I had to code it this way:

```
Forms![Navigation Form]!NavigationSubform.Form!ControlName
```

To my surprise this code continued to work when I added further forms within the Navigation Forms tabs and had controls named the same as one in question. I guess `NavigationSubform` automatically points to the tab with the current focus.

Comment: I've made an update. Can you give it another try? Also removed all the `[` and `]` which I think aren't needed in this case (unless you have spaces in the form names) or have called them something odd.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm away from PC so can't test what I'm saying. Looks like Parfait will get to the solution for you soon.